# Use access token with Reactjs Frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I made an authentication API with Nodejs, Expressjs, MongoDB, and JWT. Now, I am making a small frontend with React-js which does just the Sign-up and Sign-in. I integrated the Sign-up and now when I try to integrate the Sign-in with the frontend, I get the access token when I hit the Sign-in endpoint. I don't know how to use the access token to authenticate the user. Can anyone please help me with this?

```js
{
    "id": "5f2bc55f5ea2f61fd8b26fcf",
    "username": "wango",
    "email": "wango@gmail.com",
    "roles": [
        "user",
        "admin"
    ],
    "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVmMmJjNTVmNWVhMmY2MWZkOGIyNmZjZiIsImlhdCI6MTU5Njc4ODgxOSwiZXhwIjoxNTk2ODc1MjE5fQ.NkGUSgQ237ifRSrPxtJCSG9W463SFy_VDGlfapNwr1U"
}
```

I have attached the code snippet of the response I get when I hit the endpoint with the username and password.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Sure, which part?

Comment: Any relevant code. Server-side would probably be best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adrian Solarczyk has said it all. So I am using localStorage as an example so after you log in you set the token to local storage like this.

```
 localStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.accessToken);
```

If you're using fetch before making a request assuming you are passing it as a header. You will need to get the token stored in local storage. So something like this.

```
 const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
```

Now you have the token you can attach it assuming you're passing it as a header on every request.

```
const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
myHeaders.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
fetch('url', {
method: 'whatevermethod',
headers: myHeaders,
})
```

You could use Axios if you prefer to but I hope this gives you an idea as to how to go about it. So whenever the user is logged out you will need to make sure you remove the token from local storage.

```
 localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just had to pass the access token in the header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your access token somehow locally on client side (cookie, localStorage, indexedDb). You will also need a refresh token to persist a continous session.
I personally recommend storing JWT in `http-only` and `secure` cookie.
Then you would attach your access token to request at each protected endpoint as

```
Authorization: Bearer {token}
```

header (or to every request depending on your backend configuration).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I do this in the routes? /api/auth/signin/:accessToken.

Comment: You probably never want to put access token in the URL, that is vulnerable to [request interception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests).

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand. So how do I use the token I get now? Because when I hit the endpoint after I get the token, it still says 'No token provided'. Where do I pass in the token?